# How serious is a letter of reprimand for a US public school teacher?

Tags: united-states, discipline, unions

My wife is a teacher in a public school and received a letter of reprimand. The boss thinks she revealed confidential information, but my wife argues she did not. She belongs to a union. How serious can such a letter of reprimand be on someone's career? Can this letter follow one from job to job? Are there some steps to take in challenging that?

Comment: Was there any disciplinary process in issuing this reprimand?  Did she appeal the decision ? 

There of course must be such a process and the ability to appeal. 

Also did the employer follow to the letter the process?

Answer (score 96):

She should immediately speak to her union representative and begin an appeals processes.  Let the Union do the heavy lifting, say little to nothing.  This is fairly serious for public education because that letter will follow her **FOREVER**  It is best to work with the union to get it removed from her file ASAP.

Comment: @RichardU Not really. There are some states that don't allow CBA's for public teachers, Georgia being one of them. So you can have a "union" but it's more like a lobby.

Comment: For public school employees represented by a union this is absolutely the answer.   Were she not a teacher and represented by a union, she should get legal assistance as soon as possible.